# Prevent select from going out of the div:

Tags: jquery, html, css

The `select` tag is going out of the background `<div>`. I don't want to give background color to `body` of html page. Any solution with HTML,CSS and jquery is welcome.

Here is the embedded code in Plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/dJTbTgedcOLyxmX07Dzj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a clear div below the `</article>` as show below

```
<article>
.....
</article>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a floated element `nav`, so you have to clear the `.nitDiv`.

Or you can add just the following:

```
.nitDiv{
      overflow: hidden; 
}
```

Preview:
https://plnkr.co/edit/dJTbTgedcOLyxmX07Dzj?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

This CSS mod also works by adjusting the size of the div:

```
.nitDiv {
      background-color: #f1f1f1; 
      display:flex;
}
```